# Spring - Injecting generic beans

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, autowired

I'm trying to inject a class with `generics`.

Let's say I have the class `GenericClass<T>` and I want to inject it in two classes having:

```
@Autowired
private GenericClass<A> foo;
```

and

```
@Autowired
private GenericClass<B> foo;
```

How can I achieve this? I thought that using a `prototype scope` would be enough.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I'm using Spring 4. Also, the best solution would be not to declare each bean in a `@Configuration` if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Spring are you using?

With `Spring 4.0` you can use generics and it will automatically consider the generic type as a form of `@Qualifier`.
Reference: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics 
so you can still `@Autowire` beans with scope `Singleton`.